# How to redirect to mountable route handlers in Express 4?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I'm using mountable route handlers:

```
router.use('/api/v1', require('./sinograms_api'));

var routes_sinograms = require('./sinograms');
router.use('/sinograms', routes_sinograms);
router.use('/sinogram', routes_sinograms);
```

This way I can relocate all my code without having to change all the paths.

It's great except that in my route handler, if I have to redirect to another route handler, the only way is to use a path.

Ex. in sinograms_api.js:

```
res.redirect('/sinograms/list') 
// where /list is a path defined in sinograms.js
```

Is there more modular way to redirect to another route handler without using a harcoded path ?

Comment: Don't think so - your best bet is probably an inline function, unfortunately.

Comment: Route handlers should be the URLs you want to support (and should not change unless you intentionally redesign your web site) and should be completely different from where the actual files are served from (which can change easily by just adjusting your server-side code).  What exactly are you wanting to move around?

Comment: @jfriend00 Let's imagine I have to relocate the api to a new version '/api/v2' or that for whatever reason (seo, new language added) I have to change the /sinograms/ to a more meaningful name /hanzi/.

I know I won't have to do it often, but what's the purpose of using modular route handlers that I can mount anywhere if I still have to change hardcoded path in redirect ?

I'm aware it's a very specific case (path changes + inter route handlers redirect) but I'm asking for the proper way to do it, as the curent relocatable routes handlers, and hardcoded redirect seems a little odd to me...

Comment: It seems you should be using a router for that type of use where you can change the top level path of the router and then have to change none of the code in the actual router.  If you're going to change the actual public URLs and you are doing `res.redirect()` in your code, then you will have to change the redirects too.  There is no way around that.  You could abstract that with your own code by making your own redirect function that takes your own invariant moniker for the root and you then add in the actual root in just one place so you only have to change one place for all redirects.

Comment: FYI, you pretty much NEVER want to change the public path of an API because when you do that, you potentially break ALL clients using that API.  Usually, you add a new version of the API at a new path.